# What happen if I made a Differential Backup without Full Backup in same drive?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-backups

I have SQL Server 2012, and a Backup drive apart, but it is really full. I want to move all the backups, after done, to a Network Drive. My concern is with the differential and log backups, as I don't know if they need to see the full backup to be done, or how does it works in SQL Server.

Is it safe to move the Full Backup to another drive, and then execute the daily differential backups?

Comment: If I were you, I wouldn't move them. I would alter the location of where all your backups are saving to and then manually run the full backup, so a fresh full backup is on the other drive. Then the differential and log backups shouldn't be a problem saving to the different location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us remember the golden rule for restoring first.

‘After restoring full database backup, restore latest differential database backup and all the transaction log backup after that to get database to current state.’

So if you have only one full backup and then keep on taking differential backup's the size of the differential backup will keep on growing everyday. In case of disaster you may have to find the older full backup and then restore the latest differential backup.

So in theory: If you take one full backup and move to somewhere else and keep on taking differential backup works.
However, there are changes that your full backup may get corrupted or your differential backup have issues. You will in that case miss another full backup.

It is always a good idea to take full backup at regular intervals. I take full backup of my databases every day when they are relatively small and every other day when they are very large.

Here is the blog post where I have written about backup timeline.

https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/14/sql-server-backup-timeline-and-understanding-of-database-restore-process-in-full-recovery-model/

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question you asked, the SQL Server doesn't access the full backup itself when it makes differential and log backups. It instead keeps track of what needs to be backed up in the database itself.

The short version of that for differential backups is "the notion of what's changed (and therefore needs to be backed up) is kept track of in what are called differential change map pages" and for log backup is "the notion of what's changed (and therefore needs to be backed up) is kept track of in the transaction log itself".

The longer (and IMO more interesting) version is [this excellent article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2009.07.sqlbackup.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#id0980034) by Paul Randal.

Answer (score 0):

To recover, you need to restore the full backup before the differential. The normal recovery sequence is to restore the latest full backup, latest differential backup after the full backup, and log backups since the differential in sequence.

The backup files obviously need to be available in order to restore regardless of where you store them. If you were to lose the local full backup, you could not restore at all. You might consider copying the full backup to the network share as an extra layer of safety.